# How i don't show same window more than one at a time

Tags: java

In my project, I create some buttons. When a button is clicked then a frame is appeard. But when I click the same button then the same window is come again. It will decrease my project quality. I want that when next time the same button is clicked then the frame is not come because the frame is already visible. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've implemented it.
Instead of creating a new frame every time, keep a reference to it, and if it's already been created just show the existing one.

Here's a simple example. It's a frame that has two buttons. One of them creates a new frame every time, and the other one creates a frame the first time you click it, and any time after that will just show that one frame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame main = new JFrame("Test");

    JButton btnAlways = new JButton("Always");
    JButton btnOnce = new JButton("Once");

    btnAlways.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame(new Date().toString());
          frame.setSize(400, 300);
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
      }
    );

    btnOnce.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener() {
        JFrame frame = null;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if (frame == null) {
            frame = new JFrame(new Date().toString());
            frame.setSize(400, 300);
          }
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
      }
    );

    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.getContentPane().add(btnAlways, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    main.getContentPane().add(btnOnce, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    main.setSize(300, 100);
    main.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

The listener for `btnOnce` has a `frame` field initially set to `null`. The first time you click the button, it will go through the `if (...) {...}`, create a frame, and assign it to the `frame` field, so that subsequent invocations don't have to, rather they will use the stored value.

Comment: how I will implement that it is already created?  Is there any method that will give me any information about existing frame? I am beginner in java.

Comment: Added a few more comments. If you're not very familiar with Java, you might want to start with a book on the language, and focus on the language, rather than user interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use `SingleTone` design pattern for the frame class..access using `getInstance()` method.